# Drupal site with same database for two sites - I need better solution

Tags: php, drupal-7

I am now working on a drupal project, the client needs same admin side and same database to save the content, But he needs visualize things separately. That is two sites running same code base. These two are sharing same contents. Such as news,reports etc.

What is the best way to implement this, I read some multisite doc, but its based on two admin side and different database.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into the [Domain Access](http://drupal.org/project/domain) module. It will allow you to use a single database for a multisite setup (sharing all users and content). One of the sub modules within it Domain Theme allows you to set the active theme for each domain (making each site look different)